# Quantifying conditional duration of values in excel

Tags: excel, count, conditional-formatting

I am trying to analyze blood pressure that is taken every minute, and determine how long the values are within a certain range, consecutively.  I have the data set up in excel for the moment.  I have color coded the values based on the ranges I would like to quantify.  I know that if I do a simple "=countIF) function I can get the total number of times these values meet the criteria.  But what I want to do next is quantify for how long the values fall within a specified range, consecutively.

[image]

This shows values in columns in excel, where each column is a different patient, and the heat map are the value conditions to help me visualize if certain thresholds occur for longer times than others.  But I want to find a way to quanitify this in excel, if possible.  Any help would be much appreciated.

The final result I am looking for is to be able to measure how much time each patient sustains a specific category of blood pressure to know if certain ranges are more prolonged than others (e.g. blood pressure is between 120-130 for 30 minutes).  So in the spreadsheet above, assuming each cell is a 1-minute bin, for column HU, BP is between 120-130 for 3 minutes (rows 2-4), and again for 16 minutes (rows 6-22).  In column HS, blood pressure is above 140 (black) for 7 minutes.

I want to find a workflow to quantify these durations so that I can get a summary of the number of consecutive 1-minute bins (each cell) at a specified range/threshold for each patient (column)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would create another sheet -- let's call it "Thresholds" -- with thresholds of bloodpressures in ascending order in column A.
Put a category number next to each value (in column B)
For example:

```
0 0
90 1
100 2
105 3
110 4
115 5
120 6
125 7
... etc.
```

Back in the other sheet, add a new column next to each bloodpressure column. So you
would have a new column HR next to HQ.
Put there a formula that looks up the category for the value in HQ, from sheet "Thresholds". 
You can use VLOOKUP for that. For example in row 2:

```
=VLOOKUP(HQ2, Thresholds!$A$1:$B:$1000, 2)
```

Then add yet another column, HS it will be.

In there make a running count for same category rows, like this (for row 2, I assume you have used row 1 for column titles):

```
=IF(HR1<>HR2, 1, HS1+1)
```

Drag down this formula to the column. This formula checks if this row has a different category of blood pressure than the previous one. If so, it
sets the counter to 1 (it is the first instance in this running series). In the other 
case it takes the value of the counter in the previous row and adds 1 to it.

Repeat this for the other columns (inserting 2 new columns next to each).

This will already give you a start for further analysis.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.  A few corrections/modifications I needed to make to account for blank cells.  For the VLOOKUP, blank data would return a #N/A, and if that or a blank is the category column (HR), then the values returned in the counting (HS) column will throw off every subsequent row.  So after the VLOOKUP, I did a find and replace to put "0" instead of #N/A, and then get rid of them after I have calculated all the consecutive counts for the real data ranges (1-9).

I'll update when I figure out how to get an accurate readout of the largest counts for each category.

Comment: I have been unable to find a way to make sense of this information with the new formatting.  It hasn't really allowed me to answer my original question, as I still have the same problem of trying to quantify the consecutive rows for each category.  Any other advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I think this might be something that can't be done in Excel.  I tried to figure it out in SPSS, but that has not been helpful either.

Comment: It would be useful if you could specify in your original question an example of the kind of output you are looking for.

Comment: I updated the description in the original question above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You could add another column which reproduces the category, but only when the next row has a counter value that is not one higher than the one on the current row. That way you get a column with only category values where the count has reached its highest. You could then filter on those rows... etc. It is not straightforward. You might want to move to MS Access for this and use SQL.